# Mysa thermostat(s) and 2 baseboard heaters

Tags: electrical, thermostat, baseboard

I'm having some problems hooking up my baseboard heaters (1500w) to Mysa thermostats.

They are both on the same breaker.  Currently they are operated by 2 thermostats that are  on the same separating wall (different rooms).  Mysa install on one of them was easy since L1 went to L1, T1 went to T1 and L2 went to the one that had the 2 wires connected. It controls its baseboard heater properly.

[image: Box with 4 wires (2 of them connected to each other)]

On the other side of the wall the box has only 2 wires (L1 & T1).  Currently I left the old thermostat in (works properly) but would also like to control this one with a Mysa.  So would kindly appreciate your feedback on how to do that exactly.

[image: Box with 2 wires]

I'm thinking of 2 options:

1. Rout the 2 wires (from the second picture) from the older thermostat to the box that has the Mysa (first picture box) and connect the L1 to L1 and T1 to T1 and have that Mysa thermostat control both heaters.
2. Replace the Old thermostat with a Mysa and connect L1 to L1, T1 to T1 and run a wire from the Mysa L2 wire to the other box and connect it to the L2 wires.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.